# How to insert array of array in phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert an array of row in database and every row of array contain 3 another rows.

```
foreach($type as $a=>$b)
    {
     $sql="INSERT INTO `actual_regular` (`employee`, `sex`, `caste`, `family`, `local`, `worked_month`, `incash`, `total_salary`) VALUES ('$type[$a]', '$sex_actual[$a]', '$caste_actual[$a]', '$family_actual[$a]', '$employee_actual[$a]', '$worked_month[$a]', '$cash_actual[$a]', '$salary_actual[$a]');";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Above will insert array of rows. Every rows contain 3 rows that will be inserted in new table

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `more_regular` (`product_detail`, `unit`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('$detail_product[0]', '$unit[0]', '$quantity[0]', '$price[0]');";
     $insert = "INSERT INTO `more_regular` (`product_detail`, `unit`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ( '$detail_product[1]', '$unit[1]', '$quantity[1]', '$price[1]');";
     $insert = "INSERT INTO `more_regular` (`product_detail`, `unit`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('$detail_product[2]', '$unit[2]', '$quantity[2]', '$price[2]');";        
mysql_query($insert); 
} // above foreach ends here
```

I mean there are multiple rows need to be inserted in table `actual_regular` every rows contain 3 more rows. These 3 rows are inserted in table `more_regular`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single insert query for three insert operations like this:

```
<?php
$insert = "INSERT INTO `more_regular` (`product_detail`, `unit`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ";
$values = array();
foreach ($type as $a=>$b) {
    $values[] = "('$detail_product[0]', '$unit[0]', '$quantity[0]', '$price[0]')";
    $values[] = " ( '$detail_product[1]', '$unit[1]', '$quantity[1]', '$price[1]')";
    $values[] = " ('$detail_product[2]', '$unit[2]', '$quantity[2]', '$price[2]')";
} // above foreach ends here
if (! empty($values)) {
    $insert .= implode(', ', $values);
}
mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

Basically, the logic is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES
(1,'Andrew'),
(2,'Glenn'),
(3,'Marvel');
```

Comment: `foreach ($type as $a=>$b)`  is already used above, so i use `foreach($detail_product as $x=>$y)` bt can't get result.

Comment: @Pupil remove that semicolon from each values `'$price[0]');` `<----`